# Compatibility of PC HDMI with Toshiba TV HDMI

Tags: windows-10, hdmi

I'm using a Toshiba TV as a monitor for a PC, using HDMI.  It works fine most of the time except that it has a strange problem sometimes.  When I do various activities such as exit from a streaming movie, it sometimes causes the HDMI connection to be disabled, such that the TV indicates no signal.  To reconnect it, I can power cycle the TV or disconnect and reconnect the cable.  Various changes get made automatically when it happens, which I have to undo.  Such as some software attempting to adapt to the video change, and needing to be set up again to undo those attempts.  And the TV itself changing modes.

How can I fix it?  Is there some kind of adapter to make it more compatible, so it won't disable the HDMI connection as mentioned above?

I considered abandoning the HDMI connection and using VGA or something.  But the PC presently has a DVI-D connector, with no VGA connector, and the TV has a VGA connector, with no DVI-D connector

The TV model number is 32E200U.  The PC has the same problem using an old or new motherboard of different brands, and different generations of Intel CPU's, several generations apart.  It uses the Intel CPU video, which is presently the 530 video.  It also happened with the very first Intel CPU video, which was in CPU's released years ago.  I'm presently using Windows 10.

Comment: Have you tried using the Ctrl+P shortcut?

Comment: What Ctrl+P shortcut are you talking about?  If I use Ctrl-P in Chrome, it wants to print the web page.  If I use Ctrl-P in Bash, it retrieves my most recent command line.  If I use Ctrl-P in VLC, it pops up a preferences window.  If I use Ctrl-P in Vim, it moves the cursor up one line.  So it doesn't make sense that a Ctrl-P "shortcut" would somehow solve this problem.

Comment: I think he meant Win+P instead of ctrl